# Enumeration Performance

Tags: c#, performance, enumeration

consider the following code example:

```
IEnumerable<Y> myEnumeration = *some linq stuff into a datatable*

If (myEnumeration.Count() > X)
{
    foreach(Y bla in myEnumeration)
    {
       // do something
    }
 }
```

Will this result in enumerating 2 times? The count-Call + the foreach? If so, is there any way to avoid one of the enumerations?

Thanks in advance

**Edited myEnumeration.Count -> myEnumeration.Count() (extension method)**

Comment: 1. Shouldn't `Count` be `Count()`? 2. You can always take a look at sql profiler to see if the data is being retrieved twice

Comment: Just asking: Why'd you need to check the `.Count()`?

Comment: When I'm faced with this issue I tend to call ToArray() when pulling it into myEnumeration. From that point on you know it's in memory and it's all been done one DB hit.

Comment: yeah, meant count()...extension method...thanks

Answer (score 3):

I put this code to LinqPad to let me show the generated SQL:

```
IEnumerable<MyTable> myEnumeration = MyTable;

if (myEnumeration.Count() > 1)
{
    foreach(MyTable bla in myEnumeration)
    {
       // do something
    }
 }
```

The generated SQL is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] AS [t0]
GO

SELECT *
FROM [MyTable] AS [t0]
```

So yes, the data will be retrieved two times from Database.
Consider

```
List<Y> myEnumeration = *some linq stuff into a datatable* **.ToList();**
```

Comment: thanks! What if I use a Dictionary instead of a datatable. And a linq statement to access some data from the dictionary.It's the same right?

Comment: No it's not the same. My answer was not about in memory operations. If MyTable or Y is an in memory object I would not recommend calling ToList() since you will do an unnecessary cast then.
But it's a huge difference to fetch Data two times from a Database over the network and working in memory.

Comment: ok, but if I do a complex linq statement to retrieve data from the dictionary? Then I will do the enumeration with the complex linq statement 2 times and there might also be a performance problem. just wondering.

Comment: You have to ernumerate twice also if it's an dictionary. My answer just shows how to avoid pulling data from a database twice. But when you cast or call foreach every time the data will be enumerated. But don't waste your time about these inmemory performce things unless you have trouble with it (but thats just my opinion).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that will give you two database calls. `Count()` will execute query like:

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table WHERE Blah
```

And then `GetEnumerator()` will execute query which gets all required fields:

```
 SELECT Id, Foo, Bar FROM Table WHERE Blah
```

---

Actually there is no one correct answer. You should consider on:

- number of results you usually get (is it millions of entities, or just several dozen)
- number of required entities (is it several entities or hundreds of them)
- what happens more often - is number of required entities present in resultset or not
- is it real performance issue, or this method will be called once a week

Depending on that you should make your decision.

- if it's not performance issue, then simply make two database calls
- if number of returned items is not huge and it's more likely they will contain required number of items, then just dump query to list
- if number of items is pretty big and you don't want to dump them all, then you can use extension method below, will check if there is at least N items in resultset without saving all sequence to list. But here you should consider what will be faster - dumping N required items, or making database call to check items count.

Here is extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeIfMoreThan<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    List<T> buffer = new List<T>(count);

    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
         while (buffer.Count < count && iterator.MoveNext())
                buffer.Add(iterator.Current);

         if (buffer.Count < count)
         {
              yield break;
         }
         else
         {
            foreach (var item in buffer)
                yield return item;

            buffer.Clear();
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
                yield return iterator.Current;
        }            
    }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
foreach(Y bla in myEnumeration.TakeIfMoreThan(X))
{
   // do something
}
```

Thus you will not need to dump all query results in in-memory list. You will use single database call (but it will query for all item fields). And you will not enumerate items if there is less than required number of results.

Answer (score 2):

It would if `Count` isn't a property, but the method `Enumerable.Count` (as I would expect). What I would suggest in this case is to make it into a list beforehand:

```
List<Y> myList = *some linq stuff into a datatable*.ToList();
if (myList.Count > X)
    foreach (Y bla in myList)
        //do something
```

Comment: What if it is a million rows in the database? `Count()` alone (without the `.ToList()`) wouldn't retrieve them all, just the number of them.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Do you have some resource where it describes that EF is doing this?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius If he was using EF he would be using an `IQueryable<Y>`, not an `IEnumerable<Y>`.

Comment: No, only what I experienced while debugging. It is certainly possible that I can be wrong.

Comment: Jeah, I think thats the way I will go. I meant count()-Extension method of course.

Answer (score 1):

It will generate two queries for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sometable
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
```

which is neither once nor twice. It will be two separate requests, but only the second one will be pulling the data. The first one will just return the number and will be way faster. If you want this to happen in strictly **one** request, use `.ToList()` at the end of the query. Then it will go through the list. You can check this in SQL Profiler too. Keep in mind two queries approach might be safer in some cases so you don't suddenly start pulling millions of rows.